# Thread Sleep After Change OS Date and Time

Tags: java, swing, timer, sleep

I have a timer task in my code that execute every second to compare if the computer time same with the time in database.

If the compare method equals zero, it will play the sound and popup `JOptionPane`.

After that I set `thread.sleep(10000)` to stop the timer task.  The reason I use `thread.sleep` because I don't want my program play multiple sound and popup option pane.

The problem is when i run the main application, I change the OS date and time the timer task to compare time will stop running.  So, the compare method will stop checking.

Does anyone have another idea to solve my problem?

Below is my code in timer task:

```
    Timer tickTock = new Timer();  // Create a Timer object
    TimerTask tickTockTask = new TimerTask(){

        // This is what we want the Timer to do once a second.
        public void run(){
            if(prayTimeGUI.compareTimeSubuh()== true){
                if(prayTimeGUI.getDisableAlertStatus()==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Waktu Subuh Telah Masuk","Sembahyang",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
                    playAlarm music = new playAlarm();
                    music.runmusic();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Waktu Subuh Telah Masuk","Sembahyang",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else if(prayTimeGUI.compareTimeZohor()== true){
                if(prayTimeGUI.getDisableAlertStatus()==true){
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Waktu Zohor Telah Masuk","Sembahyang",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }else {
                    System.out.println("Date1 is equal to Date2");
                    playAlarm music = new playAlarm();
                    music.runmusic();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Waktu Zohor Telah Masuk","Sembahyang",
                            JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                }
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(60000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }               
        }

    };

    tickTock.schedule(tickTockTask, 0, 1000);
```

Comment: 1) Please add an upper case letter at the start of sentences.  Also use a capital for the word I, and abbreviations and acronyms like JEE or WAR.  This makes it easier for people to understand and help. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) Please don't forget to add a '?' to questions!  Some people do a search in the page for '?' and if none exists in the 'question' go directly to the next (actual) question in line.

Answer (score 1):

Just fire up a `Thread` and move your logic into that instead of in a `TimerTask`.